# Modifying value in multidimensional array by path in array (or any) format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array representing a potentially unlimited deep category tree menu which looks like this

```
this.tree = [{
    "title": "1. dragon-breath",
    "items": []
}, {
    "title": "2. moiré-vision",
    "items": [{
        "title": "2.1. tofu-animation",
        "items": [{
            "title": "2.1.1. spooky-giraffe",
            "items": []
            }, {
                "title": "2.1.2. bubble-burst",
                "items": []
            }],
    }, {
        "title": "2.2. barehand-atomsplitting",
        "items": []
    }],
}, {
    "title": "3. unicorn-zapper",
    "items": []
}, {
    "title": "4. romantic-transclusion",
    "items": []
}];
```

and then I have an array path to one of tree leaves, that dynamically changes in time and can look like this

`var path = [0]`

next time it can look like this

`var path = [1][1]`

or this

`var path = [1][0][1]`

Now I need to change the title attribute of leave represented by this path. I cant find any decent way how to do it. Only thing, that came on my mind was eval function,

`eval('tree'+getStringPathByArrayPath([1,0,1])+'.name = "'+updatedName+'"')`

which I find kind of evil and also I am using this function as angular ng-model (getter/setter) so I dont want browser to evaluate this over and over.

Is there any decent way how to solve this or do I have a bad approach to this problematic?

PS: I cant just iterate over the path array recursively and get to the right tree leave node by node, because there is no passing by reference and every time I assign one  subnode to variable, I get a copy (but I need to change the original).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No, path can't look like that.

Comment: It would help to see some code running in jsfiddle.

Comment: @minseong can you please explain why?

Comment: sorry, my fault - path actualy looks like [0] or [1,1] or [1,0,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Javascript is pass-by-value, the value of any variable holding an object is a reference to the object.  Passing such a variable will pass the reference, not a copy of the object.  So this will change your tree:

```
var node = this.tree[path[0]];
for (var i = 1 ; i < path.length ; i++) {
  node = node.items[path[i]];
}
node.title = updatedName;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a thoughtful response and it helped me solve my struggle. I still dont know how to solve similar problem without jsons (just a multidimensional array), but I dont need it right now. So thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an *Array* defining the properties to access to get to your desired value;

```
var path = [1, 0, 1];
//          x  y  z
```

You also have some corresponding object

```
var obj = [
// y     0           1        // x
// z   0    1      0    1     //
    [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], // 0
    [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]  // 1
];
```

You could write a function to get to the value thus

```
function followPath(root, path) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < path.length; ++i)
        root = root[path[i]];
    return root;
}
```

and in this example you'd get

```
followPath(obj, path); // "f"
```

Comment: Thank for reply, but as I said in PS, I need to modify those values in the array (have an angular getter/setter) and because JS has no passing by reference, modifying this returned node of your function does not modify the original...